# Count months from now

Tags: php, date, calendar

I'm using [Max's Calander](http://php-script.hu/script/bovebben/max_s_calendar) at my page. It requires to use this time format: Y,n (for example: 2008,3)

How to generate 12 month from now?

I tried this:

```
$myCelandar->showCalendar(date("Y".","."n"));
$myCelandar->showCalendar(date("Y".","."n", strtotime("+1 month") ));
```

But it won't work.

Comment: `"Y".","."n"` O_o what is going on there? Should be just `'Y,n'`

Comment: you gotta tell us who's Max?

Comment: http://php-script.hu/script/bovebben/max_s_calendar

Comment: Down vote, cause you put the answer in your question just needed to change ```strtotime``` value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   $myCelandar->showCalendar(date("Y,n", strtotime("+1 year")));
```